# Border Radius not Working for Fieldset with Legend in IE

Tags: html, css

I have had trouble using border-radius on fieldsets with a legend. It works ok with all desktop browser except IE. With IE the corners are not rounded. If I take out the legend, the fielset's corners are rounded.

I have found the following CSS fix, but it seems convoluted because of the need to use float and adjust the top margin on the legend:

```
    <style type="text/css" >
    fieldset, legend {
        margin:20px;
        padding:0 10px 10px;
        border:1px solid #666;
        border-radius:8px;
        box-shadow:0 0 10px #666;
        padding-top:10px;
 }  

legend {
        padding:2px 4px;
        background:#fff; 
    }


    fieldset > legend {
        float:left;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }
    fieldset > legend + * {
        clear:both;
    }
    </style>
```

Does anybody know any "cleaner" alternatives?

BTW: I'm using Bootstrap 4, if that maters.

ADDED HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css" >
    fieldset, legend {

        border:1px solid #666;
        border-radius:8px;


 }  

legend {
        padding:2px 4px;
        background:#fff; 
    }


    fieldset > legend {
        float:left;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }
    fieldset > legend + * {
        clear:both;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Legend</legend>
            <br />
          <p>Fieldset</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Stuff</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: It's happening on IE 11

Comment: share your html code also so we can try to fix.

Comment: I added the html above.